# Best practice for making a django webapp restart itself

Tags: python, django, caching

We have certain sysadmin settings that we expose to superusers of our django webapp. Things like the domain name (uses contrib.sites) and single sign-on configuration. Some of these settings are cached by the system, sometimes because we want to avoid an extra DB hit in the middleware on every request if we can help it, sometimes because it's contrib.sites, which has its own caching. So when the settings get changed, the changes don't take effect until the app is reloaded.

We want the app to restart itself when these changes are made, so that our clients don't need to pester us to do the restart for them.

Our webapp is running on apache via mod_wsgi, so we should be able to do this just by touching the wsgi file for the app whenever one of these settings is changed, but it feels a little weird to do that, and I'm worried there's some more graceful convention we should be following.

Is there a right way to apply updates that are cached and require the app to reload? Invalidating the caches for these things will be pretty hairy, so I think I'd avoid that unless the app restart thing has serious drawbacks.

Comment: What webserver are you making use of for your app?

Comment: I would usually consider a situation where an app has the ability to control its own environment a security risk.  Unless there is a very safe and simple way to do this I would recommend looking at cache invalidation or giving the user an out-of-app option for reloading.

Answer (score 2):

For mod_wsgi read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Some other WSGI servers have similar options, but options in other WSGI servers are usually more limited.

Answer (score 1):

If you use WSGI and your process is being watched by a controller like supervisord, gunicorn, uwsgi or similar then you can simply send yourself a SIGINT or SIGQUIT (depending on controller). It should shut down the current process gracefully and the controller will restart it for you.

```
import signal, os
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGQUIT)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on apache with mod_wsgi, just update the timestamp of wsgi config file everytime you make change to a model. Apache automatically restarts the application if the wsgi file gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup:

- If you are using wsgi on a single server you could touch the wsgi file to let apache restart every instance of the app
- If you are using gunicorn you probably use supervisord to controll it. Then a supervisorctl restart APPNAME would be the solution
- If you scale your app on multiple servers you have to ensure that every server restarts their instances. There are several ways to achieve this:

  - use the same filesystem if you are using mod_wsgi then a touch would count for every server
  - log in to the other servers using ssh and make them restart your app

I am sure there are more ways to restart your app but it highly depends on your setup and whether or not you have to restart all instances or only one.